# `\ref`erence in uppercased header (memoir + hyperref)

Tags: hyperref, header-footer, memoir

I would like to reference something in a header, while still having it upper-cased. Is it possible to "protect" the `\ref` commands?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Comes before Chapter \ref{s:2}}
\label{s:1}

\clearpage

Some text on next page so we can see the heading.


\chapter{Comes after Chapter \ref{s:1}}
\label{s:2}

\clearpage

Some text on next page so we can see the heading.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the best solution at the moment (interacting with hyperref is not an easy matter), is to make sure to define those labels to use uppercase letters.

Comment: Note that this is not just `memoir` related, the same issues occurs in `book`+`hyperref` and `book`+`hyperref`+`textcase`

Comment: @daleif You mean something like redefining the references so that **only** uppercase letters are used in the label text (i.e.: replacing `s:1` and by `SA`, etc.)? Wow, it works. (Pause for a second.) WOW. it. works! How..?

Comment: `S:1` would be enough here. The problem is hyperref redefining `\ref` such that textcase (which memoir uses) cannot stop the argument of ref to be turned into uppercase before applying ref to it. Having the label already in uppercase makes the header uppercase g of the ref arg do nothing and thus the ref works even in a hyperref applied header.

Comment: Thanks! I have added an answer, but if you submit one as well I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is actually not related to `memoir` as the problem also occurs if you switch to `book`. Interestingly, the problem disappears if `hyperref` is removed.

And that *is* basically the culprit. When `hyperref` is loaded `\ref` is redefined in such a manner that its contents is no longer exempt from being uppercased before `\ref` then acts upon it. That is why you'll see LaTeX complaining about unknown references `S:1` and `S:2`.

In `memoir` we have a copy of the `textcase` package thus we apply `\MakeTextUppercase` instead of the normal `\MakeUppercase`, but at least in headers that cannot  deal with `\ref`, it still ends up uppercasing the contents of the `\ref` argument before `\ref` is applied.

For now the best solution, is to low practically make sure that the labels, that are going to be used via hyperref in a header, are written using uppercase letters. That way uppercasing the `\ref` argument does not change anything and the ref resolves.

Thus instead of

```
\chapter{Comes before Chapter \ref{s:2}}
\label{s:1}

...

\chapter{Comes after Chapter \ref{s:1}}
\label{s:2}
```

use

```
\chapter{Comes before Chapter \ref{S:2}}
\label{S:1}

...

\chapter{Comes after Chapter \ref{S:1}}
\label{S:2}
```

---

Additional: The reason why we see the problem in the header is because the header is constructed using, say, `\markboth` which performs a `\unrestored@protected@xdef` but under `hyperref`, `\ref` is already protected and we essentially end up with `\MakeTextUppercase{... \protect\ref{s:1}} in the header, thus during upper casing`\ref` is left alone, but its argument is still expanded, thus causing the issue. (explain in chat)

Comment: Do you mind if I edit, adding the changed source (so I can remove my answer)?

Comment: I don't think there is any need to add the changed source. I'll add an example instead