# reference in the running head and babel

Tags: babel, ref, headline

If section title contains a reference like `\section{Proof of Theorem~\ref{maintheorem}}` and we load babel, but not include `\nouppercaseheads` then LaTeX in interprets `\ref{maintheorem}` as `\ref{MAINTHEOREM}` and reports a missing reference. One can fix it by `Theorem~\lowercase{\ref{maintheorem}}`.

However it does not work if the label contains also uppercase letters like `{MainTheorem}`

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage[english.us]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{headings}
%\nouppercaseheads

    \begin{document}
    \title{Some crap}
    \author{A. Author}
    \date{\today}
    \maketitle
    \section{Results}
    \begin{theorem}\label{maintheorem}
    \blindtext
    \end{theorem}

    \section{Proof of {\ref{maintheorem}}}
    \blindtext
    \newpage
    \blindtext
    \newpage
    \blindtext
    \newpage
    \blindtext
    \end{document}
```

Comment: This is a problem in any class.  A good discussion appears in comments on this question: [`\ref`erence in uppercased header (memoir + hyperref)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438298/579)

Comment: Indeed, however there is discussion about hyperref and in my case it is babel which messes things up.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need shorthands in refs (or bibs), just write:

```
\usepackage[english, safe=none]{babel}
```

The reason is explained in the question linked by @barbarabeeton wrt `hyperref`, because it's exactly the same (a protected `\ref`). In the case of `babel`, `\ref` is redefined to make it ‘safe’ if shorthands are used to name labels. See p. 15 of the manual.